# Difference between @media and viewport

Tags: css, html

How does @media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) differ from meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"

I tried to place them both but nothing changes.

Answer (score 0):

@Media only screen support IE9-10 and windows phones-, where as meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" only support browsers like Chrome, Safari, Fire-F and Opera

Answer (score 0):

Viewport :You're setting your mobile browser's viewport's width to be equal to your device width.For all the devices and desktops

Media Queries:A media query consists of a media type and zero or more expressions that check for the conditions of particular media features. Separate mediaqueries  for each resolutions of the devices